# proc glmselect training and testing

Tags: sas

Looking at this code:

```
ods graphics on;

proc glmselect data=analysisData testdata=testData
               seed=1 plots(stepAxis=number)=(criterionPanel ASEPlot);
   partition fraction(validate=0.5);
   class c1 c2 c3(order=data);
   model y =  c1|c2|c3|x1|x2|x3|x4|x5|x5|x6|x7|x8|x9|x10
             |x11|x12|x13|x14|x15|x16|x17|x18|x19|x20 @2
           / selection=stepwise(choose = validate
                                select = sl)
             hierarchy=single stb;
run;
```

Taken from [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glmselect_examples02.htm). I understand that you explicitly define the training (analysisData) and testing dataset (testData). What I do not fully understand is the PARTITION statement. Does it mean that the analysisData is partitioned to use one half of the analysisData for training and the other half for 'testing' aka validation to establish how, for example, the selected independent variables of a candidate model perform? In other words, the testData is never used for training, as I would expect.

PS:

Btw, how can I create analysisData and testData from a originalDataset with a 80/20% split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are correct.  Look at the documentation on the `PARTITION` statement:
http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/68162/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_glmselect_syntax10.htm

> requests that specified proportions of the observations in the input data set be randomly assigned training and validation roles. You specify the proportions for testing and validation by using the TEST= and VALIDATE= suboptions. If you specify both the TEST= and the VALIDATE= suboptions, then the sum of the specified fractions must be less than one and the remaining fraction of the observations are assigned to the training role. If you specify a TESTDATA= data set in the PROC GLMSELECT statement, then you cannot also specify the TEST= suboption in the PARTITION statement. If you specify a VALDATA= data set in the PROC GLMSELECT statement, then you cannot also specify the VALIDATE= suboption in the PARTITION statement.

So half of the data in `analysisData` will be used in Validation and half in Training.  The data in `testData` will be used for Testing.

PS Answer: Look at the Data Step in the example you linked to.  It uses a random uniform and `2/3` to split the data approximately (2/3, 1/3) between analysis and test.  Change the fraction in that statement to .8 to get what you want.  Alternatively use the `PARTITION` statement as outlined in the documentation.